# YUI 2 Editor - JavaScript event within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, editor, yui2

I can easily wrap a text selection with span tag through a button click like this;

```
this.toolbar.on( 
    'testClick', 
    function(o) 
    {
        var sel = myEditor._getSelection();
        myEditor.execCommand('inserthtml', '<span class="test">' + sel + '</span>');
        alert(myEditor);
    }, 
    myEditor, true);
```

What I am trying to achive is to bind this span class ('test') within the iframe to a javascript event;

```
testEvent = function {
    alert('Hello World!')
}
```

Any ideas if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

```
var sel = myEditor._getSelection();

YAHOO.util.Event.addListener( sel, 'click', anyMethod, anyContext );

function anyMethod( e, anyContext )
{
   alert(clicked);
}
```